# js merge carousels sliders are breaking when js merge

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, conflict, owl-carousel

After js merge carousels sliders are breaking in the site, followed no-conflict and other solutions, also in the console this is showing

> Uncaught TypeError: jQueryowlCarousel is not a function

can you help me on this issue

Comment: Can you show your script for your carousel?

Comment: ya sure, can i give the screenshot?

Comment: yes, sure, please share

Comment: http://prntscr.com/md5v2l

Comment: no it is production

Comment: Magento 1.9 or 2?

Comment: magento 1.9 version and this issue only when js merge is kept

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: jQueryowlCarousel is not a function

This error means you called the function `jQueryowlCarousel` before it was defined.(Due to JS merge)

I assume you have a third party slider script and you calling it from your PHTML file.

**Simple solution** should work as move the slider script to the head tag of the page.

**To debug the Issue:**

1. Open your merged JS file and find out the location of slider scripts where the function **jQueryowlCarousel**  was defined and script where you calling the function. Script where you calling the function should come after the script where the function jQueryowlCarousel was defined. 
   **Or you can also check in Browser view source.**
2. Disable JS merge.
3. Move that slider script to the head tag.
4. Clear the cache and enable the JS merge.

Comment: when js is merged it is showing 3 files, jquery min is calling in one file and owl carousel file calling in another file

Comment: See in browser which sequence they are loading.

Comment: Basically the script where function not defined error showing, should be loaded after the function definition.

Comment: in that sequence first jquery is calling next is owlcarousel